# Passing structure fields as arguments to functions, C

Tags: c, linux, struct

I have an interface with the following rough layout:

```
#define MLIST       5
#define MLISTBUF    1024

typedef struct {      
    char*        name;     
    int16_t      lenbuf;               
    uint8_t      apbuf[MLISTBUF];   
} parmList; 

typedef struct {
     //....more fields here

     parmList aplist[MLIST]; 

     //....more fields here
} Interface
Interface aComm;
```

I need to "pack" `apbuf` field into a larger buffer and send it via TCP protocol. [image: largerBufferToSend]

I have a function that is responsible for packing the message properly and then sending it.

```
void b_sMessage( uint8_t type, int16_t lenbuf, uint8_t buffer[])
{
    b_addApMessage(lenbuf, buffer);

    b_send();
}
```

I just have a problem with passing the field `aComm.aplist[].apbuf` properly. I can't pass it in the form of, because the message will be sent 5x and will not be understood by the system.

```
for(int index = 0; index < MLIST; index++)
{
    b_sMessage(type, aComm.aplist[index].lenbuf, aComm.aplist[index].apbuf);
}
```

Is there a way to pass the `aComm.aplist[].apbuf` field to a function so that it can be called as follows. How to switch the pointer to multiple `aplist` arrays? I would not want to pass on the entire structure due to its size and data containing

```
b_sMessage(type, aComm.aplist->.lenbuf, aComm.aplist->.apbuf);

void b_sMessage( uint8_t type, int16_t lenbuf, uint8_t buffer[])
{

    for(int index = 0; index < MLIST; index++)
    {
        b_addApMessage(lenbuf, buffer);
    }
    b_send();
}
```

Comment: I confess that I'm having a lot of difficulty following your description of the problem.  However, I get the idea that the issue is that you want to pack multiple `apbuf`s into one message before sending.  In that case, either you must separate the message packaging from the message sending, or you must pass *all* of the needed apbufs to the function at once.  One way to do the latter would be to send a whole aplist, and maybe its length, instead of a single apbuf.

Comment: Check `sizeof(Interface)`; it will exceeed 5 kB. The whole point of the packing in TCP is to **not** send unused parts between `apbuf[i]` and `apbuf[i+1]`. As for the question itself, `aComm.aplist->.lenbuf` just is not valid C. No matter how you write `b_sMessage`, it can't take illegal C constructs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parmList` array like:

```
void b_sMessage( uint8_t type, parmList list[])
{

    for(int index = 0; index < MLIST; index++)
    {
        b_addApMessage(list[index].lenbuf, list[index].apbuf);
    }
    b_send();
}
```

and call it like

```
b_sMessage(type, aComm.aplist);
```

This will not pass any structs but just a pointer to a `parmList` struct.